# android and ksoap, check web service availability

Tags: android

I am trying to create an android application that uses Ksoap2,
I wanna check the web service availability before using any processing,
because if i don't my program just crash.

Comment: What about wrapping your transport code into `try/catch`?

Comment: Then you tried it wrong, coz it should work. You can share your code so smn would point you to your mistake.

Comment: I shared my code, thank you for your interest

Comment: It seems that there's no unhandled exception. Post the stack trace of the exception that cause a crash.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try SOAP UI (http://www.soapui.org/). It provides a GUI of SOAP service so that you can run and see if returned data is null or not.