# webservice availability check in android

Tags: android, web-services

What should be the factors considered while checking if webservice is available or running in android? FYI I am using HTTPGet object to send a request. I am currently checking only timeout exceptions.

Thanks..

PS Also checked [android and ksoap, check web service availability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138980/android-and-ksoap-check-web-service-availability) but it doesn't seem to point me to a direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public boolean isConnected()
{
    try{
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService
                                                    (Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected())
        {
            //Network is available but check if we can get access from the network.
            URL url = new URL("http://www.Google.com/");
            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(2000); // Timeout 2 seconds.
            urlc.connect();

            if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200)  //Successful response.
            {
                return true;
            } 
            else 
            {
                 Log.d("NO INTERNET", "NO INTERNET");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

More faster way is using HttpGet request and DefaultHttpClient:

```
public boolean isConnected(String url)
{
      try
      {          
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpClient.setKeepAliveStrategy(new ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy()
            {
                  @Override
                  public long getKeepAliveDuration(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context)
                  {
                           return 0;
                  }
            });
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            return response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200;

      }
      catch (IOException e){}
      return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check the [**HTTP Status Codes**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)