# Android Check if WebService is available on port

Tags: java, android, connection

I need to check if a service is running on a specific IP:PORT/service/ and if its not then fallback to another one. I am doing this on a single place in the app.

Is there a way to just PING it if its alive instead of trying to send a valid request to it and catch a possible IO error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i solved this is:

We implemented a Ping method on the backend at `/service/ping` which responded with status `HTTP_OK (200)`. i walk through each IP address i need to test with a very short connection timeout set and see if i get to one where i receive a successful connection (status returned is 200).

I had to go through all the IP's on a local wifi network and find where my local network service was hosted. Since the devices are connected to the same wifi network i have setup a connection timeout of 200ms which was more than enough to make sure the check was fast.

Answer (score 0):

Refer accepted answer this question for web service availability check, if webservice is not there (else condition) then try fallback connection

[webservice availability check in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507535/webservice-availability-check-in-android)